# To mock a mockingbird: What question to ask

Tags: logical-deduction

This puzzle is from [To Mock a Mockingbird](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/To_Mock_a_Mocking_Bird.html?id=NyF1kvJhZbAC&redir_esc=y) goes like this -

> There is a question I could ask that has a definite correct answer -
>   yes or no - but it is logically impossible for you to give the correct
>   answer. You might *know* what the correct answer is, but you cannot
>   give it. Anybody other than you might possibly be able to give the
>   correct answer, but you cannot!
>   Can you figure out what question I could have in mind?

I am not able to get anything out of this. Could you please help me out by suggesting some approach? I am *not* looking for solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, I think this is the answer (or the question, or whatever, aaa...) from the book is...

> "Is 'NO' your answer to this question?"

Explanation / Approach.

> You have to find a self referential question that includes "Yes" or "No" in it. And ask the question in such a way that the answer contradicts itself.

Comment: Thanks, but I am more interested in hints rather than the answer itself (which is given in the book anyways).

Comment: that's why I added an explanation. The answer is here for people that don't want to look for the book.

Answer (score 6):

Hint:

> The fact that *anybody other than you might possibly be able to give the correct answer* indicates that there's something special about **your answer**. So the question must specifically reference **your answer**.

Another hint:

> It's a yes/no question, and both possible answers (yes/no) must lead to a contradiction.